# applying conditional blur filter style in Angular2 is not working

Tags: angular, styles, blur

am having a div when I want to apply the blur filter on it but conditionally, like "

```
          <div class="card" [style.filter]="visibile?'blur(0px)':'blur(3px)'"
</div>
```

and inside the component

```
this.visible = true // or false
```

but am not getting this style, other styles like opacity, background-color and others are working if I apply like above, but not the filter style

any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use ngClass instead :

```
 <div class="card" [ngClass]="visible ? 'blur' : ''"
 </div>


 @Component({
   //..
   styles:['.blur{filter:blur(3px);}']
 })
```